# Scan python link and iframe it?

Tags: python, django, linux

i want to execute one python code and try to get output in  browser

```
import os
tools=os.popen('pip list | seashells').read()
```

output is this link

```
serving at https://seashells.io/v/rWXx9XvF
```

how to iframe the link generated in terminal ?

i try to store this seashell generated link in python veriable and iframe in html code but cuould not do it? i neeed help!!